# How to check the maximum number of selectors in stylelint?

Tags: sass, lint, stylelint, scss-lint

I need to check that there is one root class in one file.
Is it possible?

```
// Error
.a { }
.b { }
```

Expected

```
// Success
.a {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with the [rules built into stylelint](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/).

However, it is possible to [create a stylelint plugin](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins/) to do this.

The plugin would look something like:

```
// ./plugins/stylelint-root-max-rules/index.js

const isNumber = require("lodash/isNumber");
const {
  createPlugin,
  utils: { report, ruleMessages, validateOptions }
} = require("stylelint");

const ruleName = "plugin/root-max-rules";
const messages = ruleMessages(ruleName, {
  expected: max =>
    `Expected no more than ${max} ${max === 1 ? "rule" : "rules"}`
});

const rule = quantity => {
  return (root, result) => {
    const validOptions = validateOptions(result, ruleName, {
      actual: quantity,
      possible: isNumber
    });
    if (!validOptions) return;
    const { length } = root.nodes.filter(node => node.type === "rule");
    if (length <= quantity) return;
    report({
      message: messages.expected(quantity),
      node: root,
      result,
      ruleName
    });
  };
};

module.exports = createPlugin(ruleName, rule);
module.exports.ruleName = ruleName;
module.exports.messages = messages;
```

You would then use the plugin like so:

```
{
  "plugins": ["./plugins/stylelint-root-max-rules"],
  "rules": [
    "plugin/root-max-rules": 1
  ]
}
```